# R Studio Desktop IDE | What is the file size limit

Tags: r, memory-management

I'm trying to open a 60 MB file in R and it states the file is too large. Does anyone know what the file-size limit is in R?

Comment: I have opened upto 900MB-1GB file in Rstudio.  I think that depends on your computer speed/limitations

Comment: See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html